# how to add mouse based horizontal scroll for this webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to add a horizontal scroll to this website it can't be shift+scroll or swipe scroll for the touchpad

complete website code can be found at 
https://github.com/itskhagendra/NYX

the website can be viewed at
https://itskhagendra.github.io/NYX/

I have tried vanilla javascript

```
var item = document.getElementsByTagName('MAIN')[0];
        window.addEventListener('wheel',function(e){
            if(e.deltaY>0)
            { item.scrollLeft +=1000;
            }
            else item.scrollLeft-=1000;
        })
```

is it possible to press shift programmatically so that the scroll can behave as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 
var body = document.body;
var html = document.documentElement;
var scrollSpeed = 35;

 document.body.onmousewheel = function(e){
  if(e.deltaY < 0){
    body.scrollLeft -= scrollSpeed;
    html.scrollLeft -= scrollSpeed;
  }else{
    body.scrollLeft += scrollSpeed;
    html.scrollLeft += scrollSpeed;
  }
}
```

```css
#scroll{
 display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: it's not working can you please look into the code and then tell me where I am wrong

Comment: I updated the previous post. you had all the sections stacked on top of each other, using flex-inline places them side by side.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure the div you're trying to make scrollable is wide enough for you to be able to scroll.

Then, you can use a lib like MouseWheel to detect scroll events and return the delta values you're going to use with scrollLeft.

The mousewheel lib: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel

The code for that would be something like this:

```
$(function() {

   $('#scrollableDiv').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);

      event.preventDefault();

   });

});
```

This solution requires jQuery.

Comment: thanks, @anazard but the solution is not working it will be great if you can have a look at the code and help me why this is not working

Comment: could you set it up on codepen?also what page is the effect supposed to be in?